# Use sklearn's PolynomialFeatures minimum degree

Tags: python, scikit-learn

The [doc for PolynomialFeatures](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html) states that:

> PolynomialFeatures = Generate a new feature matrix consisting of all polynomial combinations of the features with degree **less than or equal to** the specified degree.

Which means that set `interaction_only`, if I have 3 input features A, B and C, it will generate 7 features: `1, A, B, C, AB, AC, BC`.

I can't think of a way to filter the combinations to keep only the combinations of features with degree **equal** to the specified degree.

ie. Generate only: `AB, AC, BC`.

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Comment: Use a regular expression to match on the feature names from PolynomialFeatures

Comment: So, you mean like, computing all polynomial features, and then removing the ones with degree 0 or degree 1? This would be equivalent to removing the N+1 first columns of the result of polynomial_features.transform, right?
But then, it's weird to compute columns just to delete them afterwards.

Comment: Yes, and it would be wasted compute and memory. Scikit-learn doesn't expose what you want. The "right" answer would be to either monkey patch the method or write a scratch implementation. If you can spare the memory/compute, filtering after is probably easiest.